# Git: Is it possible to PUSH via HTTPS while the Port 22 outbound is blocked?

Tags: ssh, git, https

In our development environment, outgoing Port 22 are blocked. And I assume the `git push ..` command sends the files via SSH/22.

We're using BitBucket. Is it possible to `git push` using HTTPS protocol instead of via SSH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `git push`, it uses the URL for the remote you're pushing to to figure out how to transmit changes. It doesn't necessarily use SSH, or port 22; that only happens if the URL tells it to use SSH and port 22. See [Git URLs in the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_git_urls) for more information.

In particular, if the remote URL is an HTTPS URL, then Git will use HTTPS when pushing.

Comment: Oh, so the protocol used in `git push` depends on what was used in `git remote origin` earlier? That means, if the repo was cloned by using **https**, then the pushing will be going through **https**?

Comment: That is the default, yes. You can configure it to what you need or want

Comment: Yes it works. I didn't know the **push** command follows the same Protocol used in the cloning process earlier. Thanks.

Comment: If someone tries to push using https in 2022 it no longer works: `remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.` This is the message I got when trying to push using https, ssh is mandatory